# My submission button will not work anymore. Something to do with my controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-5

My submission button won't post any information into the database or redirect itself back to the home page after pressing the button. Need help pointing out potential errors in code

This is for a rails app that I have to submit for class. I've tried changing the where the submission button was in the html file. changing the error checking, and the form. but submission button and update action will not start

**edit.html.erb**

```
<div>
<h1 align="center">Edit Recipe</h1>

    <%= form_for :recipe, url: recipes_path, method: :patch do |f| %>
    <% if @recipe.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@recipe.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
        this recipe from being saved:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @recipe.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<h2><strong><%=f.label :Title %></strong></h2>
<p>
    <%=f.text_field :title %>
</p>

<h2><%= f.label :Description %></h2>
   <p>
     <%= f.text_field :description %> 
  </p>
  </div>

  <div> 
<h2><%= f.label :Instruction %></h2>
  <p>
    <%= f.text_field :instruction %>
    </p>
   </div>

    <div> 
<h2> <%= f.label :Ingredients %></h2>
    <p>
    <%= f.text_field :ingredients %>
  </p>
  <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
  </div>

    <% end %>
    <%= link_to 'Back', home_page_index_path %>
```

**recipe_controller.rb**

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @recipes = Recipe.all
    end
    def new
        @recipe = Recipe.new
    end
    def show
        @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
    end
    def create 
        @recipe = Recipe.new(recipes_params)
        if @recipe.save
            redirect_to @recipe
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end
    def edit
        @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
    end
    def update
        @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
        if @recipe.update(recipe_params)
            redirect_to @recipe
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end
    private
        def recipes_params
            params.require(:recipe).permit(:title, :instruction, :ingredients, :description)
        end
end
```

**recipe.rb**

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
    validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
end
```

Comment: Hi, can you please add the logs from the server?
Also, you can replace the line introducing the form_for with this one:
`form_for(@recipe)` - it will build the path on it's own :) You can inspect the generated html in the browser/

Comment: I would take a closer look at your erb file -- the html seems to be malformed. This could potentially have bad drawbacks when the erb file gets rendered. Good luck on your class!

Comment: But do you know what happens when you press the button? Can  you use your browsers development tools to see if it actually submits the form? And/or inspect the server/rails logs? Besides, I agree: clean up some of the html tags (indenting the code consistently helps identifying issues around that).